# How to remove indexed pages from google effectively

Tags: seo, php, search-engine-indexing, sitemap, traffic

[image: e]

My site was getting traffic and it was on the rise, then I added https and somewhere in that time I also created tons of extra link for google to crawl, thinking this will increase traffic in those area where there was no traffic.

It backfired, my traffic reduced from 900/day hits to some 300 now. I have implemented 301 redirect for subdomains (subdomain somehow had duplicate pages so removed it) and then there was PHP script where I created these extra links, I don't know what properly unindex them now.

It has been 5 days since I made those changes, still the indexed pages are still in 55k which is huge. My site originally had 11k index pages, then rose to 100k and now at 55k. How can I remove those 'extra links' from index that I had created using PHP Script. Note I had asked google to index the whole page that I created and index all the links coming out of it.

### PHP Code

This is the code where I created these links (forcefully). Basically my website is city base. I am pulling all cities, and then force them to use all the tags I have for all the cities.

```
<?php
$result1 = getDistinctBizCities();

if($result1 != false)
{
  while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    echo '<h2>Businesses in '.$city.'</h2>';
    $result = getTags();
  {
    $city = ucfirst($row1['city']);

    if($result != -1)
    {
      echo'<ol>';
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {

        echo '<li><a href="/search.php?keywords='.$row['tags'].'&city='.$row1['city'].'">'.$row['tags'].' in '.$row1['city'].'</a></li>';     
      }
      echo '</ol>';
    }   
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion and I have already tested it -  the best way of removing pages from index comes in a few phases:

1. On the pages you want to remove from index implement no-index.
2. Create a temporary `sitemap.xml` with URLs of these pages.
3. Ping this `sitemap.xml` file to Google using GSC or http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=URL/of/file

Comment: This would require to make custom sitemap.xml as the ones available online creates a regular sitemap

Comment: It would, but thats a 10 minute job... @slowdiver

Comment: what about not xml page, regular links..will that work?

Comment: You can use this for example: https://timestampgenerator.com/tools/xml-sitemap-from-list

Comment: I set all of my deleted pages to 410,i m frustrated how slow google is.people should avoid deleting because of this slow as snail proccess.

Answer (score 1):

I would fire the `410 Gone` as a header - so Google quickly learns these pages are away and removes them fast from index.

Like

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '(url-pattern-to-remove-1|url-pattern-to-remove-2)') {
       header ("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone");
     }
?>
```

Comment: [This](https://www.peshawar.co/tags_search.php) is the link to that page, what is your recommendation. Just remove the links and set the headers?

Comment: Because these links are valid otherwise, but I forcefully created them, do not have any valid contents.

Comment: If yout just remove them, I think they remain in the index database and Google will try to re-visit them. But if they remain and fire the 410 header Google deindex them just after first revisit

Comment: I am thinking of setting `$header= ('HTTP/1.1 410 Gone'); and then echo that from search page and run the script. Temporarily it should remove these pages but will effect other pages too.. Well in fact I have made all search pages NoIndex as I probably should make google crawl this page. What do you say

Comment: I would prefer 410 before noindex, which can be too slow and not mandatory

Comment: For example if you visit on the the link [Doctors in Chitral](https://www.peshawar.co/search.php?keywords=Doctor&city=chitral), and see source. You will see on line 6, NoIndex. Shouldn't that be enough to remove?

Comment: Google can be very slow at proceeding noindex, specially if it recognizes content behind noindex

Comment: I set all of my deleted pages to 410,i m frustrated how slow google is.people should avoid deleting because of this slow as snail proccess.

Answer (score 0):

To remove indexed pages from SERP first you need to delete those pages and set redirection to the contact us page or which ever particular page might be.

After the site gets crawled again check that particular page appears on search results or not.

If the page still appears on search results you need to request Google to delete the page with the help of GSC.
Steps to be followed to delete the pages which are appeared on search results.
1. Login to your webmaster tools.
2. Go back to the previous version of webmaster tools (i.e old version)
3. On the left-hand side, a menu will appear.
4. Click on Google Index and select remove URL's.
5. Copy & Paste the URL and follow the instructions.
6. After a few days you can check the status whether the page is deleted or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may remove URLs from Google temporarily by using the `Remove URLs` feature the the Webmaster tools. As of this date (Aug. 2019), this feature is still in the *old* Webmaster tools and can be found on the following URL:

`https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal?hl=en&siteUrl=https://example.com`

^ Replace `example.com` with your domain. From the menu, it is location under `Google Index > Remove URLs`

If there is a pattern in your URL, you can remove the **entire directory** by selecting that option in the dropdown. For your example PHP code, this would be `search.php`

[image]

I should also note: This isn't neccessarily an index issue - the index is a symptom of the primary issue, which is your wasted crawl budget.

By adding your scripting, you have drastically increased the number of pages needed to crawl by the Googlebot beyond your website's crawl budget. This really makes a mess of things and makes it harder for your other content to be more sticky in SERPs as they have a lower priority in your site hierarchy now due to the flood of irrelevant pages.

If you were to view your crawl stats, located on `https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-stats?hl=en&siteUrl=https://example.com` (again, old version of webmaster tools not yet present in the newer search console), you will almost certainly identify a sharp spike in crawl when you added the script, but the spike will nowhere be enough to crawl the sheer volume of pages you created programatically.

Please add a `noindex` directive on all pages contains `search.php` to ensure the URL removal process will go smoothly, so if Google recrawls those pages that they will not reappear in the index.