# Google reports no discovered URLs in my sitemap and thousands of errors

Tags: google, google-search-console, php, sitemap, xml-sitemap

My question is related to my previous question [How to remove indexed pages from google effectively](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121308/how-to-remove-indexed-pages-from-google-effectively) where I was advised to create XML sitemap and submit it to google. The advice looked solid so I created one.

Now when I created my custom sitemap and submitted to google, it did not pick any url of it and basically every url has error in it. I did replace &,',",(space) and other characters to properly url encode all the links but I am still getting the error. I did verify my sitemap from third party (xml-sitemap) and it reported no error. I want to know what am I doing wrong

[image]

[image]

Here is the sitemap snippet

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>
www.peshawar.co/search.php?keywords=&amp;city=peshawar
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-03-10</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
www.peshawar.co/search.php?keywords=17%20Inquiry&amp;city=peshawar
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-03-10</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
www.peshawar.co/search.php?keywords=3D%20Printers&amp;city=peshawar
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-03-10</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

Here is the [actual sitemap](https://www.peshawar.co/test.xml) which contains 34k links and takes a while to download. Could it be the size of XML that is causing the problem? (Highly unlikely though)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. The issue was likely, the urls were missing http:// at the start, thus URLS were invalid. I have also added extra headers at the top.

[image]

Here is the final XML snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>

      <loc>https://www.peshawar.co/search.php?keywords=asdfasd&amp;amp;city=peshawar</loc>

      <lastmod>2019-03-10</lastmod>

      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>
   <url>

      <loc>https://www.peshawar.co/search.php?keywords=asdfasdf&amp;amp;city=peshawar</loc>

      <lastmod>2019-03-10</lastmod>

      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>
```

Comment: Very strange format for a sitemap. A sitemap is to list the pages in the site, not a search. I hope this works for you.