# How to remove bulk urls from google index

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, url-removal

I have URLs indexed by Google and I want to remove them from indexing. I found that I can use bulk remove option by providing a CSV file including all indexed URLs to Google Search Console. I have tried to get a CSV file with the method below but I got this error:

> ```
> =importXml("http://www.google.com/search?q=site:mysite.example&num=100&start=1",
> "//h3/a/@href") error : Could not fetch url
> ```

How can I get a list for my indexed URLs?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not adding 'noindex' to the meta tag in the HTML of the pages via your site's CMS? This is cumbersome but most likely the best way of ensuring those pages get deindexed. If it's a page volume issue... I'm not one to tell you to run to a plugin but others may recommend you look there (and deactivate it after). But if it's under say 200 pages, I would do it manually. Let me know what you decide.

Comment: `Is there a reason you're not adding 'noindex' ` - `noindex` can be VERY slow. Beside of this, Google revisits noindexed urls to get into knowledge, whether they are indexed again. 410 works once and forever.

Comment: I added noindex tag but the total link number is massive and i am searching for a quick way.

Comment: You can't remove URLs using Google Search Console unless they have been removed or blocked on your site.   If you remove or block them, they will get de-indexed within a couple months without you having to do anything.  The removal tool just speeds up the process.  Do you really need them removed so quickly?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to identify your site URL which is indexed in search results. The command to check all your indexed URL's is site:www.example.com.
All the results are shown for your site.

In order, to remove the URL's which are of no use or which contains old content first thing you need to delete the page & redirect that particular URL to the contact us page.

After few days when the site has again crawled again check whether the deleted page appears on the search results or not.

If it again appears you need to remove that page from GSC.
Steps to follow:

1. Login to your webmaster accounts.
2. Select Google Index.
3. You will get a drop-down menu with 3 options i.e 
   A. Index Stats
   B. Blocked resources
   C. Remove URL's
4. Select Remove URL's
5. You'll get a new window that is with a button named as "temporarily hide".
6. Click on the button and paste the URL and click continue.
7. A new window will be triggered with a drop-down menu of 3 options.
8. Based on your requirement select one option and continue.
9. After a few days, you need to check the status in webmaster tools whether the page is deleted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't need these urls, the most simple an efficient way is to make them deliver status code `410 Gone`. Immediately Google crawls these urls, it removes them from index. Look at my answer here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/121309/43910

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all of these are spam URLs or the expired pages which are still indexed in Google.

In this case, you can use the method explained by these guys. https://anicca.co.uk/blog/wordpress-site-hacked-fake-spam-urls-resolved/

It helps to remove thousands of spammy links, expired pages etc.

All you would need to do is 
1. Return 404/410 status code 
2. Create a separate sitemap and submit it to google (refer the method to create a sitemap)
3. Wait for a few days till Google crawls and removes all of these pages.